# which order to start learning google sample codes

Tags: android

HI i am new to Android

I needed guidence from experienced programmers in this site

I have executed "Hello world" program and simple ones, i found out the best way to lean android programmig is by practicing Google sample codes, i downloaded through eclipse and placed on eclipse workspace

I have ambuiduity in which programs to start like proj1--- then --- proj2 ---later---- proj3

if i randomly open some project the code is complicated and i am lost

it would help if someone direct me to learn the order of projects i need to follow to practice

please share your experience

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar position. I've been doing a few things at once:

1. Following the training through from
   http://developer.android.com/training/index.html
   in order. There's a lot there, I got to about half way through 'getting started' before I was ready to try creating my own app.
2. Reading the guides on a topic when I start to use it and want to know more
   http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html
3. Working on a *simple* application idea of my own to give me some focus. I've been hacking away at it learning as I go. I found this was better than following someone else's example as I was motivated to see my app work, and it's actually pretty easy going so far. I've been using the Google docs and searches (lots of Stack Overflow threads) to help.

Now I'm at the point where I'm going back and improving the implementation of my app, looking at bits of it I think are messy and researching if there's a better way to do it. Which is all good learning too.

I've only been using the sample apps as a reference if I want to see how something specific was done.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, I find it easier (once you have your idea) to design an example User Interface to display how you want the system to work for the user.  This helps keep things more User Friendly once everything is published. I'd suggest looking at example UIs from various Android Apps in Google Play or by finding example source code at places like GitHub.com, like this Ribbon Menu:

https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu

Once you have the UI designed, you should move on to designing the network/protocols which drive the background communication.  Then it's as simple as connecting the Graphics with the Built-in Sensors and communicating with your network using HTTP, GCM, and/or Sockets.

To further your resources, there are tons of examples on GitHub which can help you learn different programming styles in a published application.  If these are still too complex for you, there are many tutorials that could easily be found a Google search of "Android Development Tutorials".  I took the liberty to find you one which looks pretty simple, applicable, and somewhat example driven:

http://people.bridgewater.edu/~arn002/csci440/android-tutorial.htm